# Python url joining with parameters

Tags: python-3.x, url, urllib

Suppose I had a URL composed of a host,(e.g. stackoverflow.com) a path in that host (e.g. `questions/ask`) and finally some url arguments (`param1=5,param2=st...`)

So the final url would have been something like
`http://HOST/PATH?param1=x&param2=y&param3=zw`

Is there a build in function which would construct that url based on the host, path and params dictionary? I wasn't able to find any way to do that which doesn't involve manual string concatenation, and I feel like this probably shouldn't be done manually if that can be avoided. (Perhaps I'm wrong, since unlike file paths, urls are platform independent and pretty consistent)

I tried using [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) and several other methods, but didn't find one that supported such a general url without some manual concatenation.

Comment: Maybe [`urllib.urlunparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunparse) or [`urllib.urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit).  You need to build a list/tuple matching the result from [`urlsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) (5 elements), then `urlunsplit()` will do what you want.

```
from urllib.parse import urlunsplit

urlData = ['https', 'stackoverflow.com', 'questions/ask', 'param1=5&param2=st', '']
url = urlunsplit(urlData)

print(url)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?param1=5&param2=st
```